# Frequency of arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to initialize an array with 50 integer values and compute the frequency of numbers in the range of `10 .. 19`. I think the problem is with the bottom part of the code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Ex1partA {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kbin = new Scanner(System.in);

    int list[]=new int[50];     
    int i=0;

    System.out.print("\n\tInput numbers from 10 to 19: \n");

    while (i < 50) {
      int value = kbin.nextInt();
      if (value >= 10 & value <= 19) {
        list[i] = value;
        i++;
      } else {
        System.out.println("!! Bad number !!");
      }
    }

    for (int value : list) {
      System.out.println("" + value);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please Specify the bottom part.. :-)

Comment: What's your problem?? It looks like a homework.

Comment: very last line "System.out.println("" + value);"

Comment: @EnginePai  why so loud

Comment: once the integers are put in it does not calculate the frequency

Comment: @user2980026 If you expect that reading the values in your array will calcultate the frequency, then your wrong. The for-each loop you wrote just print the values that are in the array. It does not calculate the frequency of this values.

Comment: `(value >= 10 & value <= 19)` should probably be `(value >= 10 && value <= 19)`

Comment: >once the integers are put in it does not calculate the frequency That is because you are not calculating the frequency. Please us your code where you do it =)

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to initialize an array with 50 integer values and compute
>   the frequency of numbers in the range of 10 .. 19.

To calculate frequency, it is better to put all numbers into `List` and count frequency using `Collections.frequency`

```
  List<Integer> freqList=new ArrayList<Integer>();
   // Add numebers to this list.

    for (int i = 10; i <20; i++) {
      int freq=Collections.frequency(freqList, i);
                      // This will return frequency of number

        System.out.println(i+"  "+freq);  
    }
```

Comment: The answer that you spoon-fed to Masud [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20207346/create-a-method-called-shortest-that-takes-2-strings-and-returns-the-string-that) just teaches him to beg for homework solutions. Please do not spoon-feed answers. Please do not encourage this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You're suffering from some design issues. Specifically, you're conflating the task of getting your numbers with the task of counting frequency.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Ex1partA {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kbin = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Get all inputs
    List<Integer> inputs = getInputs(10,19);
    //Count the frequency
    Map<Integer, Integer> freq = countFrequency(inputs);

    for (int key : freq.keySet()) {
      System.out.println(key + ": " + freq.get(key));
    }
  }

  public static List<Integer> getInputs(int min, int max) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    System.out.print("\n\tInput numbers from 10 to 19: \n");
    int i=0;
    while (i < 50) {
      Integer newNumber = kbin.nextInt();
      if (newNumber < max && newNumber > min) {
        list.add(newNumber);
      } else {
        System.out.println("Bad number. Ignoring.");//Note this simply skips, does not ask for re-entry of bad numbers
      }
      i++;
    }
    return list;
  }

  // Finds the frequency of the input list and out puts it as
  // a map of number => how many times that number appears
  public static Map<Integer, Integer> countFrequency(List<Integer> input) {
    Map<Integer,Integer> freq = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
    for (Integer val : input) {
      Integer currentCount = freq.get(val);
      freq.put(val, currentCount + 1);
    }
    return freq;
  }
}
```

Lets note a few key points:

- Each function should do exactly ONE thing, if at all possible. So here we have a function that gets all the inputs (within a certain range) and another that counts the frequency of a list of numbers.
- Using full objects rather than primitive arrays gives you a lot of flexibility and power without overhead of you having to manually massage data.
- In particular, the concept of a `Map` is important here. You are 'mapping' a key (which in this case is the input value provided by the user of a number between 10 and 19) with a value (which in this case is the number of times that number appears in the list of numbers you have).
- && rather than & to apply the boolean AND to two other boolean operators.
- Note that the [Collections API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) provides frequency-counting methods that would allow you to avoid doing the mapping yourself.

Answer (score -1):

You do not need an array of size 50. For your problem since you know numbers will be in the range [10,19], create an array of size 20. Using arrays you can implement something like this

```
    Scanner kbin = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = 0;
    int arr[] = new int[20];
    // fill the array with -1, it will be used for counting
    // can be done using a for loop as well
    Arrays.fill(arr, -1);
    System.out.print("\n\tInput numbers from 10 to 19: \n");

    while (i < 50)

    {

        int value = kbin.nextInt();
        // check the value is in the specified range
        if (value >= 10 && value <= 19) {
            // treat the array index as your repeated number
            // if the number occurs again, just increment it by 1
            arr[value] = arr[value] + 1;
            // move to next input
            i++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("!! Bad number !!");
        }

    }
            //start with index 10 as we know the range
    for (int j = 10; j < 20; j++) {
        // check if value stored is greater than -1
        // if it is greater than -1 then we have a number in the specified
        // range
        if (arr[j] > -1) {
            // need to add +1 because the array was initially filled with -1
            System.out.println(j + " Occurs " + (arr[j] + 1) + " times ");
        }
    }
```